# Porque me sale DataSet no admite System.Nullable<> al establecer datos en Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

me sale error con Nullable al momento de establecer los datos a mi Crystal Report

Como motor de datos utilizo un modelo, es el mismo modelo que recibe los datos y se los establezco a mi Crystal Report

```
namespace SistemaControl_API.Models
{
   public class Get_IDDepartamento
    {
        public int IdDepartamento { get; set; }
        public int IdUnidad { get; set; }
        public int IdEmpresa { get; set; }
        public string NombreDepto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdResponsable { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Colonia { get; set; }
        public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CveMunicipio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CveEstado { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Telefono2 { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string FuncionPrincipal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> EstatusDepto2 { get; set; }
        public string NUnidad { get; set; }
        public string NombreEmpresa { get; set; }
        public string NombreEdo { get; set; }
        public string NombreMpio { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Nombre2 { get; set; }
        public string Apellido1 { get; set; }
        public string Apellido2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

así establezco los datos:

```
var GetList = _Departamento_Business.GetIdDepartamento(idDepto, idUnidad, idEmpresa);

var DatosDepto = Mapper.Map<List<Entidad.Get_IDDepartamento_Result>, List<Datos.Get_IDDepartamento>>(GetList);

 ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
 rd.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/Reports/CatDeptosCR.rpt"));
rd.SetDataSource(DatosDepto);
```

son los mismos datos y hasta son del tipo string, que podría estar pasando?
Lo más raro es que ni tienen campos nulos.

Comment: que pasa si intentas quitar los `Nullable<>` de las propiedades solo para validar que sea el tipo de dato el problema, como ahs comentado no tienes ningun dato nulo por eso podrias probar ver si es ese el problema

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, si era eso, ya me había salido en otro modelo y al revisarlo vi que ese modelo no tenía ni un Nullable<>, de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Quita los `Nullable<>` de las propiedades:

```
public Nullable<int> IdResponsable { get; set; }
```

a

```
public int IdResponsable { get; set; }
```

Tal como indica Leandro en su **[comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19787/porque-me-sale-dataset-no-admite-system-nullable-al-establecer-datos-en-crysta#comment31629_19787)**.

Comment: @Lalo: ¿si te ayudó esta respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada por favor?